# passing context to ng-template when used by its local reference

Tags: angular, antd, ng-template

I have a component that looks like this:

```
<nz-collapse>
  <nz-collapse-panel *ngFor="let item of items" [nzHeader]="collapseHeader">
    <div class="item">
      <!-- some content here -->
    </div>
  </nz-collapse-panel>
</nz-collapse>

<ng-template #collapseHeader let-item>
  <nz-divider [nzText]="item.name"></nz-divider>
</ng-template>
```

How can i pass each item as context to my ng-template? the library doesn't offer a way to do it. (nzHeader only exepts strings and TemplateRef as arguments, no other type of views)

Comment: I can't really figure out a clean way to do it. I guess a hacky way to do it would be to create a small component that would take "item" as its @Input(), and its HTML would have the <nz-collapse-panel> element at its root (without the ngFor obviously), an ng-content inside, and the ng-template afterwards. The template would not require a template variable anymore since "item" is defined in the component itself. Then, your *ngFor line refers to your component instead of nz-collapse-panel.

Comment: @NicolasB I think your solution is actually the best in this case, not hacky at all.

Comment: @NicolasB you should add it as the answer.

Comment: Alright, I've posted it as an answer. Let me know if it all works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve the issue is to completely bypass the need for giving context to a template. Instead, let's give an `Input()` to a component, because this is easy.

Let's create a `CollapseWrapperComponent` with `app-collapse-wrapper-component` as its selector. Here's the `ts` and the `html`:

```
export class CollapseWrapperComponent {
  @Input() public item: Item;
}
```

```html
<nz-collapse-panel [nzHeader]="collapseHeader">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</nz-collapse-panel>

<ng-template #collapseHeader>
  <nz-divider [nzText]="item.name"></nz-divider>
</ng-template>
```

And then in the parent component's `html`, we can now iterate over this component in our `*ngFor`:

```html
<nz-collapse>
  <app-collapse-wrapper *ngFor="let item of items">
    <div class="item">
      <!-- some content here -->
    </div>
  </app-collapse-wrapper>
</nz-collapse>
```

Now we basically have one `<ng-template>` for each `item`, so no need for context.